# How to define parameters in the adjustedCurves package for estimating confounder adjusted survival curves?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, confounding

I'm trying out the `adjustedCurves` package in R for estimating confounder adjusted survival curves, and I'm starting with the standard "lung" dataset demonstrated in the examples in http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/cox-proportional-hazards-model.

When I run the below code against the "lung" dataset, such code based on the description provided in https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/adjustedCurves/vignettes/introduction.html for "Direct Standardization", I get the error message "*Error in ate_checkArgs(call = call, object.event = object.event, object.censor = object.censor,  : Cannot handle missing values in the model coefficients (event)*". I've tried skipping over the NA fields using the `na.action = ...` in the `adjustedsurv()` parameters, I've tried replacing all NA values in the entire DF with 0's, but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(adjustedCurves)
library(ggplot2)
library(survival)
library(survminer)

head(lung) # check out lung dataset

lungMod <- lung %>% 
  mutate(event = status-1) %>%
  mutate(group = as.factor(sex-1))

outcomeModel <- survival::coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ age + sex + ph.ecog
                                + group, data= lungMod, x=TRUE)

adjSurvLung <- adjustedsurv(
  data = lungMod,
  variable = "group",
  ev_time = "time",
  event = "event",
  method = "direct",
  outcome_model = outcomeModel,
  conf_int = TRUE,
  na.action = "na.pass"
)
```

**Corrected example using Denzo's solution:**

```
outcomeModel <- survival::coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ age + ph.ecog
                                + group, data= lungMod, x=TRUE)

adjSurvLung <- adjustedsurv(
  data = lungMod,
  variable = "group",
  ev_time = "time",
  event = "event",
  method = "direct",
  outcome_model = outcomeModel,
  conf_int = TRUE,      
  na.action = "na.omit"
)

# look at Cox model by running the below; before Denzo's solution the group coefficient was all NA
outcomeModel

plot(adjSurvLung, conf_int=TRUE, linetype=TRUE)
```

Resulting plot:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misread the error message. It says `Cannot handle missing values in the model coefficients`, not that there are missing values in the *dataset*.

If you take a look at your Cox model, you will see that the model coefficient of the `group` variable is in fact `NA`. If any of the model coefficients are missing or infinite, the `adjustedsurv` function will be unable to perform the required calculations.

In this case, the reason for that `NA` value is that `group` is simply a different version of `sex` and you include both in the model formula. This is an extreme form of co-linearity (the variables are identical), which results in a missing coefficient. It can be easily fixed by omitting `sex` from the formula. Since you also do have missing data in your `lungMod` data set, you should also set `na.action` to `na.omit` or simply keep the argument on its default value.

I happen to be the developer of this package, so if you have any other questions I am happy to help.

Comment: I figured you might be the developer when I read through the package documentation! Thank you for the package and for the guidance!